# How to keep track of replies with AWS sqs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I am using AWS sqs to pass along jobs from webservers to a worker manager which launches ec2 workers.  When a message is passed to the  worker manager, it reads it and launches a worker.  I want to return the workers IP.  How would I go along implementing this?  Should I create a separate queue for responses and label the messages some identifier to keep track of a job or some other way?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Jobs should have IDs, probably UUIDs or something similar. Then you need to send a "reply" message to the task originator somehow, with the ID. However you do that it will **not** be via the same SQS queue that the manager received the message. Your question doesn't provide enough details regarding the process that creates the original message for me to give a concrete answer regarding the method of sending a "reply" message.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the clarity.  I am going to implement a separate sqs for replies.  I will also use UUIDs to keep track of jobs.

Thanks again

Comment: @h3y4w note SQS [assigns a MessageId](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/ImportantIdentifiers.html) each message. This ID is returned to the original producer when the message is sent, and is also visible to the consumer receiving the message and is ["considered unique across all AWS accounts for an extended period of time."](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/Amazon-SQS/1343#05) These are currently UUIDs but the value is not constrained in the design of SQS. To safely code against this, you should assume it's an opaque string up to 100 characters in length.

Comment: I would just use a separate UUID and not rely on SQS generated IDs at all. Or use database keys if the message is linked to a database record.

Comment: What if I input all jobs into a database (I was planning on doing this) and use its primary key as an ID.  Because it auto increases, it will always be unique.   Sorry about the post issue.  Was on the mobile app.